# Magento 2 search using REST APIs

Tags: magento2, php, api, rest-api, curl

I'm getting crazy with PHP curl and query string against Magento 2 REST Api. 
I have the following query:

```
http://mystore/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10
```

coping and pasting it in the browser it works fine. If I use PHP and curl like in this example:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://mystore/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10");
...
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        ...
    ]);
return curl_exec($curl);
```

Magento return an "Invalid signature" error.
I found the problem, is the encoding of "&" character, but I tried using urlencode() or htmlentities(), I cannot find a solution. It works only substituting "&" with "& amp;" (without space), but the query is not correctly interpreted. Which is the correct way to send the query string using PHP curl?

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

```
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
$ch = curl_init("http://mystore/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://mystore/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you @sohel-rana,  your example works fine. But doing the same thing, using OAuth instead of session based authentication,  I obtain the "invalid signature" error. Do you have the same example with OAuth?

Comment: 'invalid signature' means you authentication is wrong. Check your authentication information.

Comment: Here is an example for oAuth: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-api/

Comment: I used the inchoo example, and it works fine. The problem is with query string. Without query string it works

Comment: Amazing this actually works, I've seen so many other similar examples that didnt so thanks so much !